# fbx exports one animation per object

Tags: animation, export

I have a baked simulation of a wall shatterinng that I'm try to export to Unity.
Everything works ok, except that when I open in Unity, instead of having a single animation with all the objects animated in syncro, what I get instead are tons of animations, one for each part of the breaking wall.
In maya, what I'd do is use "combine" to join the different parts of the wall. But ni blender, "join" turns the object into a single mesh, making my wall a single mesh. I'm a bit confuse.